# Copy directory from linux to windows

Tags: linux

please can someone help me, i've got a directory that has directories in it with a format of

yyyy-mm-dd (example: 2013-12-09 ) i want to setup a script that will copy yesterday's dated directory to a windows server which handles backup's everyday. what i mean is if the script ran today it would copy the 2013-12-08 folder to the destination

Distro: Ubuntu to windows server 2003 SP2

can anyone help point me in the right direction.

Comment: I would use samba to give both servers a single filesystem they can both cope with

Comment: try `man find` and look at date related tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for starters:

```
date -d ’1 day ago’ +’%Y/%m/%d’
2013/12/08
```

So, for your exact format, you would use:

```
date -d ’1 day ago’ +’%Y-%m-%d’
2013-12-08
```

So, depending on what you want exactly, you could run something like

```
cp -r `date -d ’1 day ago’ +’%Y-%m-%d’` somewhere
```

which will copy folder "2013-12-08" and all its contents to a folder called "somewhere".

Comment: How could i use that in a bash script ? could you give me an example as for the %y %m %d do i need to input anything there

Comment: Just copy and paste the first line I suggested into a terminal and hit enter. You will see it works out what date yesterday was for you - which I presume is the name of your folder. It fills in the %Y, %m and %d for you automatically based on the date. Change the slashes to dashes and change the order of the %Y/%m%d part according to how you want it to come out.

Comment: Note there are two different types of quotes in there - single quotes which just hold strings together and backticks `` which execute the command between them.

Comment: perfect that works nicely, thanks

how would i schedule this to copy to a windows share ? any suggestions ? new to linux

Comment: Step 1. I presume you have got the Windows share mounted and visible to the Linux box? Step 2. Save the code above in a script, make it executable with "chmod +x scriptname" and check you can run it from the command line with "./scriptname". Step 3. Add an entry to your crontab to get it scheduled every day. Email me, if you are stuck - mark at thesetchells.com